# Go: Robfig Cron Scheduler Running but not Calling Functions

Tags: go, cron, scheduler

I wrote the below code to test out the github.com/robfig/cron library and the function doesn't seem to work. I change the time to one minute after local time to test and it never gets called. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong since I mimicked the code on go dev.

Link to Go documentation: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/robfig/cron#hdr-Usage

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/robfig/cron"
)

func funcScheduler() {
    c := cron.New()
    
    c.AddFunc("0 12 14 * * *", func(){fmt.Println("Hello World")})

    c.Run()

}
```

Comment: Check the error returned by `AddFunc`, it is likely that you are passing the wrong number of fields (6 instead of 5). If that *is* the case then you are probably unknowingly using `v3`. For how to use `v3` see the docs [here](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/robfig/cron/v3) and the readme [here](https://github.com/robfig/cron). And don't forget to execute the code within `main()` because the `funcScheduler` function by itself will not be invoked.

Comment: Thank you!!! I learned how to check the error and I was able to see that I was putting the minutes into the hours field. I only needed 5 entries. After I fixed that it worked! Plus I learned the importance of checking errors. Sometimes the code runs even though an error happens. Super useful!